# How do I find a specific ship at a discount?

Tags: elite-dangerous

How do I find a specific ship near my current location?

Can I find this ship at a discount? What systems offer a discount?

I'm looking for a method that works to find stockists for any ship, rather than answers listing current stockists for just one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to buy ships at a discount all Li Yong-Rui systems always have 15% off, whether you're pledged to him or not.

Here is a tool that shows you which ships are in stock at a system near you. This is for the FDL, but just change the ship name in the address for whatever you're looking for (though it doesn't show discounts right): http://roguey.co.uk/elite-dangerous/ships/fer-de-lance/where.html

If you have the option look for high population systems with a high tech economy, as these tend to have better modules in outfitting to kit your new ship with.

Comment: Additionally, all LYR control system shipyards stock at least the Cobra, Diamondback, Asp, and Python. Alternatively, players with a permit to the Founders World can find *all* ships at Jameson Memorial in Shinrarta Dezhra at a 10% discount